# IBM ODM, ADD RULE USING REST API

Tags: ibm-odm

Is there any way I can add or delete a rule in IBM ODM using Java rest api from client.

```
I was able get the value but i am  trying to find out if there is any way we can add or delete rule in the records.
```

Comment: When you say add or delete a rule, do you mean in Decision Centre (the authoring tool) or in Decision Server (execution engine)?

What is it you want to achieve, and the process you are trying to build?

Comment: I believe you can not make changes Decision Server ( Ruleapp files) but you can change rules in Decision Center ( I guess it would be ant db call).

Comment: looks like there is business rules embedded you can use to do this for some sort, but rest full service is can only support rule set and above

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible!

First rules are meant to be like decision logic. Technically changing the rules in runtime cannot be done.

Second, It depends on which component of ODM you are using. If you are using **Decision Center/Rule Team Server**(Used for authoring the rules by Business team) or **Decision Server/Rule Execution Server**(Used by developers for creating and maintaining the rules). It is indirectly possible to change the rule in Decision center using the **Decision Center API** that is provided by IBM ODM.

Third, You can set rule property active as false for ignoring the rule while building as [Dias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3326018/dias) said in the previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bala. Do you have any samples or programs that you can direct towards, when you said "It is indirectly possible to change the rule in Decision center using the Decision Center API that is provided by IBM ODM."

Answer (score 0):

When you say add or delete a rule, do you mean in Decision Centre (the authoring tool) or in Decision Server (execution engine)?

What is it you want to achieve, and the process you are trying to build?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ODM version you are running, you can use the `'Active'` characteristic of Business Rules, no matter what the type is (Decision Tree, Decision Table, Action Rule, etc).

When changed to `'false'` this will be ignored within the Rule Orchestration you provided through the Main Rule Flow.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an api to add/edit/delete rules and decision tables.  [See this link.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP76_8.8.0/com.ibm.odm.dcenter.samples/topics/tpc_tsauthoring.html)  Also google for "rtshelper.java"

The API is localhost:PORT/dcclient